# PHP MySQLi Prepaired Statement's returns false

Tags: php, database, mysqli, mariadb

I'm having a problem with a prepaired statement system though a system of Classes that managed our DB Table Entries.

So the problem i'm having is that the generated SQL of

```
INSERT INTO `sys_User` SET `email` = ? `last_name` = ? `password` = ? `encryption` = ?
```

on the line below `$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);` is failing (returning false)

However i'm not getting an error back from the Database engine,

```
Array
(
    [Number] => 256
    [String] => MySQLi Query failed MySQL said ''.
    [File] => /var/www/models/table/base.php
    [Line] => 282
)
```

Inside a base class for all Database Table Classes.

```
$db = self::getDatabase();
$bindParamArgs = array();
$bindParamArgs[] = "";
$sql = "INSERT INTO `".$this->getTableName()."` SET ";
foreach($this->updated as $name => $val){
    $sql .= " `".$name."` = ?";
    $bindParamArgs[0] .= $columns[$name]->Type;
    $bindParamArgs[] = &$this->values[$name]; 
}
echo $sql;
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
if(!$stmt){
    \trigger_error("MySQLi Query failed MySQL said '".$stmt->error."'.", \E_USER_ERROR);
}
$result = \site\model\Database::getEvaluatedBind($stmt, $bindParamArgs);
```

Some Needed Info:
`self::getDatabase();` Returns the connection the the Database (MySQLi) object

`$this->getTableName()` get the table name for the table we're working in this is worked out from the class name that has been called

`$this->updated` an array of all columns in the Table equal to boolean true if it has been modified and needs to be saved.

`\site\model\Database::getEvaluatedBind(mysqli_stmt &$stmt, $params)` a custom method i created of calling bind_param that keeps the damn pass by refference system happy,

This must be something so simple i'm missing i just can't work it out

Comment: You need to comma-separate the column-placeholder pairs.

Comment: OMG thank you @jeroen i'm testing now i have been looking at this whole system to long if im missing stuff like that.

Comment: did you try $db->error?

Comment: echo $sql;  then copy and paste the output in command line client. In case of a prepare statement use syntax "PREPARE xyz FROM <output>". Then look at parsing error,

Comment: @GeorgRichter your wrong as i don't want to do a `select` and thats what prepair is for. it's an insert also i don't want to save the statement i want to use it there and then and let the engine forget about it... http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/prepare.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**the answer is based on @jeroen's comment above**

this here is running into your error:

```
INSERT INTO `sys_User` SET `email` = ? `last_name` = ? `password` = ? `encryption` = ?
```

it should be:

```
INSERT INTO `sys_User` SET `email` = ?, `last_name` = ?, `password` = ?, `encryption` = ?
```

Comment: I have marked it as answer as it is correct but could you also mention at the top of your awser that this was a comment by @jeroen just he gave me the answer first as a comment :)

Comment: @didn't see that. yeah of course i'll link him